# How to align two TextView in a LinearLayout in the same line

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextView in a LinearLayout, I want to align them one to the left (or center) and one to right in the same line. How to do this? I try to use gravity but they ignore it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code so we can tell you where your mistake is.

Comment: @Guian done, gravity is set but they ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`.

You can use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and  `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`. Or to center it use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

[See here why gravity won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792767/how-to-right-align-in-linear-layout/20792808#20792808)

You are using `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity` which is what you would want. [This post should help clarify the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

[The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) show you available properties.

Answer (score 1):

`android:gravity` is used to set the gravity of content inside the view. However, in your case the width is `wrap_content`, hence the content has nowhere to go in the text views.

Use a `RelativeLayout` with `layout_width` as `match_parent`. Then use the `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`with the textViews.

Answer (score 1):

Use it with or without the android:gravity in the second textview and try .

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If LinearLayout is Vertical, you can put only an object per line.
You can use RelativeLayout, or else put in a line a LinearLayout Horizontal, that contains textviews

ex.

`<LinearLayout vertical>
    <LinearLayout horizontal>
        <textview 1></>
        <textview 2></>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all my issues with GridLayout...is the best thing bcos u don't need to align anithing to nothing...just put what u want into the matrix (row,column)...and this will allow you  to visualize all the field in exactly wrap content of your datas also in landscape is perfect!